# How to handle empty groups in a repeated measurements two way ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

Suppose you have N individuals you would like to test. You test at the same time for two categorical conditions where condition one could be A,B or C and condition 2 could be W,X,Y,Z. You test every individual n for every combination of these two conditions and the result is a dependent variable:
--> So basically you have 3*4 = 12 groups you would like to compare using a two way repeated measurements ANOVa

Suppose now that you have a minimal criteria you're results have to meet: If they don't meet this criteria there not included in the group: so the number of individuals in a group can be less then N and not every individual can be found in every other group.
--> still ANOVA can be performed if checked for sphericity.

Now it comes: But what if one of the groups is empty. Not due to mistakes but simply due to the fact that no good results can be obtained in that group. You're fully aware off that.
But at this point performing a two way ANOVA isn't possible anymore it seems.

Any suggestions on how to avoid this or how to turn this around?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can analyze this as a multilevel model instead.

Comment: If I test every individual on 20 different ways (being 5 different models and 4 different ages) then the number of higher level groups seem to be max 20 ---> doesn't multilevel modelling demands a higher number of higher level groups?

Comment: In a multilevel model, the people are the higher level units.  You 20 (or 19?) measures per person. What's your sample size?

Comment: thanks for answering
*I have a group of max 81 people. Each individual is tested by 20 measures (5 models*4startingages for fitting)
* the quality of my fitting is determined by the sum of squares divided by degrees of freedom : I've choosen 0.3 as a limit.
* because of this limit is not every individual fitted in every group and is there one group with no data
* most groups have around 50-70 individuals

Comment: If you can assume the data are missing at random (or missing completely at random) a multilevel model sounds like the way to go.  There's a Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_modeling_for_repeated_measures